# JSTL split array of strings

Tags: string, jsp, split, jstl, el

I am receiving a string which is of type"filenmae1:format,filename2:format"so for eg it would be abc:cvs,bad:PDF.
I want to split this string such that I can get the file names and formats.
I don't know how long the string would be,as it would be sending numerous file names and formats or sometimes just one.
I tried to split by the ,however I am unable to split by : to get the individual file names.
I first set a var with the string value.then split the string using , delimiter. Now I want to loop through and split by : and get the individual file names and corresponding formats.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you show up some sample of your code?

Comment: <c:set var="allDocs" value="${files.fileInfo}"></c:set>. I store the string in allDocs. Then setting another variable called parsedDocs which is split on , delimiter. Then for each in parsedDocs split on :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this but it's better to do this logic in backend:

```
<c:set var="filenameFormat" value="${fn:split(str, ',')}" />
... loop filenameFormat ...
<c:set var="oneFilenameFormat" value="${fn:split(filenameFormatElement, ':')}" />
```

Comment: I chose to update the Model rather than split on the front end.